# JUnit can not discover test programatically inside a Spring Boot application packaged as a JAR

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit

I have an existing application that I have wrapped inside a spring boot application to provide it with a REST API. The application uses JUnit at its core to run some tests (I am aware this is not conventional).

Since the introduction of Spring Boot, the application is no longer able to find the `jupiter-engine` and my test methods.

Interestingly enough, running the application from the IDE (Intellij) works fine. But as a standalone jar (`java -jar`), it does not.

I looked in the packaged jar, everything is stored in the `BOOT-INF` directory. Without Spring, the directory structure is flatter without the `BOOT-INF` directory (obviously).

My test cases are stored in the package `scenarios`. My application is in `com.foo.bar.app`. Note that my test cases are in the `main` package and **not** in the `test` package.

(Again, I know it's unconventional, but they are not regular unit tests.)

I used to discover test cases with

```java
        LauncherDiscoveryRequest request = LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder
                .request()
                .selectors(DiscoverySelectors.selectPackage("scenarios"))
                .build();
```

However, with spring I am only able to discover them as follows.

```
        LauncherDiscoveryRequest request = LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder
                .request()
                .selectors(DiscoverySelectors.selectPackage(""))
                .build();
```

Yet, the launcher is not able to launch the `TestPlan` since it can't find the engine. I am getting the feeling that `JUnit` is looking in a hardcoded path, which is outside of the `BOOT-INF` directory.

I did some additional testing and I found that

```java
DiscoverySelectors.selectMethod(className + "#" + method)
```

fails with

> Could not load class with name: `scenarios.path.to.class`

The test class is packaged together with the application, but it's in the `BOOT-INF` directory.

Are there some configurations I am missing?

Comment: Maybe you need to add depedency as implementation not test provider. Can you show dependencies?

Comment: Are you using mvn or gradle?

Comment: I am using gradle and the dependencies are added as implementation